# Is there a minimum wisdom score for a creature to have instinct?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores

Imagine if you will that a living human was completely stripped of their knowledge, conditioning and higher intellect reducing them to a mere instinctual level.

Is there a minimum wisdom score that such being could have?

Comment: I think [Feeblemind](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/feeblemind.htm) spell may be related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1

Absent special circumstances, the minimum score a normal living creature can have in any attribute is 1 - less than 1 indicates a creature is paralysed (str/dex), dead (con), or comatose (int/wis/cha).

In 3.X era D&D, the minimum intelligence required for something to be sentient is 3 - something with an Intelligence of 1 or 2 has animal-level intelligence and is unable to learn language or comprehend morality (which is why all animals are True Neutral regardless of how they behave).

There's no corresponding caveat for Wisdom scores, however. As long as a creature has at least Intelligence 1 and Wisdom 1 it is capable of getting by on instinctive behaviour. However, many animals have quite high Wisdom scores to represent their instinctive cunning and perceptiveness.

If you were going to apply an effect which strips away higher intellect and reduces someone to instinct, you should probably just set Intelligence to 2 and leave Wisdom alone.